# Reading list manager?

Tags: applications

Does anyone know of an app for managing a reading list?

Features I'd like to get include being able search names and authors from some kind of book database, link to common book sellers (Amazon, Barns & Noble, etc.) and add books via an ISBN bar-code.

Answer (score 4):

I have used this **[Book Catalogue](http://www.appbrain.com/app/book-catalogue/com.eleybourn.bookcatalogue)** program to enter my book collection. It lets you enter books via ISBN (manually or scanning), has a search feature and works great.

It has bookshelfs where you should create on for a reading list, although there is a checkbox 'have read the book' also ...

Check it out if: maybe it has enough of the features you want to be useful.

I like it very much.

Comment: What does it export the data as?  Is there a desktop app you can import data into?

Comment: @Bryan Denny: it exports the data as csv. And no, there is nu desktop app , yet - I'm a programmer , you never know :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use good reads here's three apps that sync with the service:

- http://www.appbrain.com/app/goodreads-droid/hactar.goodreads
- http://www.appbrain.com/app/mybookdroid-%28books-library%29/org.zezula.bookdiary
- https://market.android.com/details?id=com.goodreads (Goodreads' official app)